# How do you start a jBPM process from Python?

Tags: java, python, django, jbpm, business-process-management

I'm trying to kick off a few jBPM workflows from a Python/Django app and would rather not add a new language to the stack. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your jBPM version is 5 or higher you can use gwt-console.
GWT console has REST interface.

For example, to start a new process instance use

http://jbpm-server/gwt-console-server/rs/process/definition/{id}/new_instance

for information how to install:

http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v5.3/userguide/ch.console.html#d0e4578

or you can download it from here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jbpm/files/jBPM%205/

see this guide for more information: http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v5.3/userguide/ch.console.html

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the documentation for [jBPM 6.1 Remote REST API](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.1/userguide/jBPMRemoteAPI.html).

The REST docs for 6.1 states:

```
[POST] /runtime/{deploymentId}/process/{processDefId}/start
```

According to the docs, it does the following:

- Starts a process.
- Returns a *JaxbProcessInstanceResponse* instance, that contains basic information about the process instance.
- The *prodessDefIdcomponent* of the URL must conform to the following regex: [_a-zA-Z0-9-:.]+
  This operation takes *map query parameters* (see above), which will be used as parameters for the process instance.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.